# lsb_release of the host OS in a Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I want to get the Operating System that I'm running on inside a Docker.

This is what my `docker-compose` looks like and I'm inheriting from the `python:2.7` image

```
 version: '2'
 services:
   robot-configuration-interface:
     build: '.'
     restart: always
     network_mode: 'host'
     ports:
       - 8000:80
     environment:
       - REDIS_HOST=localhost
       - DEBUG=true
     volumes:
       - ~/logs/fetchcore-server:/var/log/supervisor
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
       - /opt/ros/indigo:/opt/ros/indigo
       - /etc/environment:/etc/environment
       - /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
       - /lib:/lib
       - /usr/lib/:/usr/lib
       - /usr/bin/:/usr/bin/
       - /var/run/:/var/run/
     privileged: true
     user: root
```

The `lsb_release -d` command returns Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (n/a) instead of 
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS even though i'm mounting `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LSB is kind of deprecated/ignored on Debian-based distributions, and the file is not present in the Docker images of the most popular distros.

/etc/os-release is prefered now.  You can see that this file is present on the Docker images of a lot of distributions (even Alpine), which is not the case with /etc/lsb-release.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is mounting `/etc/lsb-release` to the volumes

Comment: This will cause the container to see the release of the machine that is running the docker daemon, which might not be the same as the os running in the container.